# Problem with adding tooltip with bootstrap (Angular, ts)

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to add a tooltip (with the help of bootstrap) to the site I am building (Angular, in ts).

***I used the link:***
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

***The problem:***

The tooltip I created looks like this:

[image]

And the tooltip I want to get is:

[image]

**My code:**

*componentName.component.ts:*

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
    Tooltip on bottom
  </button>
```

*index.html:*

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

  <!-- For tooltips: -->
  <script>
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
  </script>
```

**The question:**
Do you have any idea where my mistake is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed data-toggle attribute on Button element. And another important question is Did you import jquery inside Angular? Native Angular way for using bootstrap is [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/)

Comment: Thank you! I added the data-toggle attribute on Button element, but the problem remained (I updated the question). Do you have another idea? I use bootstrap V4

Comment: For Angular (not angular js) the best solution is ngx-bootstrap. It's simple to use and compatible with bootstrap markup and you could use v4 or v3. Using Jquery with Angular cause performance issues and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed bootstrap v4 and v5.

The markup of your component is from [bootstrap v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#markup) and
the javascript-code from [bootstrap v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere).

Comment: You're right! Thanks! I adapted the two pieces of code to fit bootstrap v4.6, but the problem still remained. (I updated the question). Do you have an idea for another reason?